# Stochastic Interest rate spot forward relationship

Tags: forward

For a stock that pays no dividends, and has constant interest rates, I know that the relationship can be described with:

$F(t) = s(t). e^{r(T-t)}$

F(t) = Forward price,
S(t) = Stock price,
r = risk free rate,
T = maturity date,
t = time now

How does the equation change, when rates are stochastic?

*edit*

From another textbook, it appears the relationship can be modeled as:

$ F(t) = s(t) / P(t) $

where $ P(t) = e^{-\int_{t}^{T} r(s) ds} $

does this look right?

Comment: You may want to have a look of [this question](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/33141/convexity-adjustment-for-futures).

Answer (score 5):

The forward price $K$, determined at time  $t$, is the amount such that the payoff at time $T$ is $S_T-K$, while the value at time  $t$ is zero. That is,
\begin{align*}
B_t E\left(\frac{S_T-K}{B_T}\mid \mathcal{F}_t \right)= 0,
\end{align*}
Where $E$ is the risk-neutral expectation operator. Then,
\begin{align*}
K&=\frac{E\left(\frac{S_T}{B_T}\mid \mathcal{F}_t \right)}{E\left(\frac{1}{B_T}\mid \mathcal{F}_t \right)}\\
&=\frac{E\left(\frac{S_T}{B_T}\mid \mathcal{F}_t \right)}{\frac{1}{B_t}E\left(\frac{B_t}{B_T}\mid \mathcal{F}_t \right)}\\
&=\frac {\frac{ S_t}{ B_t} }{\frac{1}{B_t}P (t,T)}\\
&=\frac{S_t}{P(t,T)},
\end{align*}
where 
\begin{align*}
P (t,T) &= E\left(\frac{B_t}{ B_T}\mid \mathcal {F}_t \right)\\
&=E\left(e^{-\int_t^T r_s ds}\mid \mathcal {F}_t \right)
\end{align*}
is the price at time $t$ of a zero-coupon bond with maturity $T$ and unit face value.

Alternatively, at time $t$,

- enter into a forward contract with forward price $K$, which has zero cost at time $t$,
- short one share with income $S_t$, and
- long $\frac{S_t}{P (t,T)}$ units of zero-coupon bond with maturity $T$.

The net cost at time $t$ is zero. At maturity  $T$,

- the forward contract has value $S_T-K$,
- the short position of one share has value $-S_T$, and
- the zero-coupon bond has value $\frac{S_t}{P (t,T)}$.

Assuming arbitrage free, the value at time $T$ is then
\begin{align*}
S_T-K - S_T + \frac{S_t}{P (t,T)} = \frac{S_t}{P (t,T)}-K =0,
\end{align*}
that is,
\begin{align*}
K=\frac{S_t}{P (t,T)}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that is a great answer. 

Please can you confirm that $P(t,T)$ is the price at time t of a zero coupon bond that pays 1 dollar at time T, i.e   $$P(t,T) = e^{ - \int_{t}^{T} r(s) ds}$$

and $B_t$ is the time value of the money market account

i.e   $$B_t = e^{  \int_{0}^{t} r(s) ds}$$

Finally, in this derivation, are you assuming interest rates to be deterministic?

Comment: I don't assume deternistic interest rate. $P (t,T)$ should be the conditioanl expectation.  $B_t$ is correct.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, to summarise then:
$$ $$
$P(t,T)$ is the expected (using risk neutral measure) price at time t of a zero coupon bond that pays 1 dollar at time T, i.e 

$$ P(t,T) = E_Q [ e^{ - \int_{t}^{T} r(s) ds} ] $$

$B_t$ is the time value of the money market account i.e 

$$ B_t = e^{  \int_{0}^{t} r(s) ds} $$

Assumptions:$$ $$
1. Stock price and the interest rate are independent.
2. The market is frictionless, arbitrage free, infinite liquidity and complete

Comment: The independence assumption is not needed.